# Reformat DateTime

Tags: c#

I have a `DateTime` in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` and I need to create a new `DateTime` object (not a string) with this format `1986-04-20T00:00:00`.

most of the examples found are parsing the datetime object into a string; I need a datetime object with the above format

Comment: DateTime objects **don't have a format**, it's only when they are converted to strings.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, a DateTime doesn't have a format unless it's output to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DateTime` does not have a format until `ToString` is called on it. Until then, it's just a collection of information about day, month, year etc.

To turn a `DateTime` into the `1986-04-20T00:00:00` format in a string, you can do this:

```
yourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
var christmasMorning = new DateTime(2016, 12, 25, 8, 15, 0);

christmasMorning.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss"); // 2016-12-25T08:15:00
```

Comment: Ok guys .. easy.... I have a guy from India who is expecting a datetime property in his web server from my application with that format...

Comment: so if I understand ... there is no way that I can pass a date time object with that format but a string

Comment: @brillox It sounds like you might be passing this to a Web Service, presumable as JSON, in which case you'd just use a JSON library to properly format the date.  If that's not the case then you need to update your question to include this information.

Comment: How is the web application in India calling your application, i.e., in what format is data passed between the two? Without this critical information it is very difficult to advise you properly.

Comment: Hi James, I am calling his web application but in the WSDL he has the DoB as a date and he just emailed me that he rquires that specific format . I ahve asked him to change his WSDL for a DoB as a string. I am passing an object not JSON

Answer (score 0):

To Format your datetime object to different formats you have to convert it into string using `.toString()` method , and use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) link to learn datetime formatting.